# Array-based MinHeap implementation in Java

Tags: java, heap

This is my implementation of MinHeap in Java.

```
public class MinHeap {

        int[] heap;
        int pos;
        int size;


        public MinHeap(){
            this.size = 2;
            heap = new int[size];
            this.pos = 0;

        }

        private void minHeapify(int index){

            int child = index;
            int parent = child/2;

            while(heap[parent] > heap[child] && parent > 0){
                int temp = heap[parent];
                heap[parent] = heap[child];
                heap[child] = temp;

                child = parent;
                parent = child/2;
            }

        }
        public void add(int item){

            if(pos == heap.length) resize();
            heap[pos++] = item;

            minHeapify(pos-1);


        }
        public void delete(int item){
            boolean found = false;
            int start = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i< heap.length; i++){
                if(heap[i] == item){
                    found = true;
                    start = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found == false) throw new IllegalStateException("Item doesn't exist.");
            pos--;
            for(int i= start; i< pos; i++){
                heap[i]= heap[i+1];
            }
            for(int i=pos; i > 0; i--){
                minHeapify(i);
            }
        }

        public int min(){

            return heap[1];
        }

        private void resize(){

            size = size*2;
            int[] curr = new int[size];
            for(int i=0; i< heap.length; i++){
                curr[i] = heap[i];
            }
            heap = curr;

        }
    }
```

Invite comments and suggestions to improve.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous "microstyle" issues; for example:

- superfluous blank lines
- missing spaces before / after symbols; e.g

  ```
    for(int i=0; i< heap.length; i++){
  ```

  should be

  ```
    for (int i = 0; i < heap.length; i++) {
  ```
- `if(found == false)` should be `if (!found)`
- redundant (and inconsistent) use of `this` in the constructor.

And there are no javadocs!

---

Also, this looks like a bug:

```
    public int min(){
        return heap[1];   // should this be zero?
    }
```

Have you >>tested<< the code thoroughly?

Answer (score 0):

#### Buggy

These lines of code suggests you want to use `[1]` as the first element:

> ```
>     int parent = child/2;
>
>     public int min(){
>         return heap[1];
>     }
> ```

The parent index can only be `child/2` if `[1]` is the root of the heap.  If `[0]` is the root, then the correct parent index would be `(child-1)/2`.  Also, returning `heap[1]` for the min element also indicates you want the heap to start at `[1]`.  However, you have these other lines of code that conflict with that goal:

> ```
>     public MinHeap(){
>         this.size = 2;
>         heap = new int[size];
>         this.pos = 0;
>     }
> ```

Here, you should set `this.pos = 1;` because `pos` is where you add your next element.

> ```
>     public void delete(int item){
>         boolean found = false;
>         int start = 0;
>         for(int i = 0; i< heap.length; i++){
> ```

Here, you should start your `for` loop at index 1 instead of 0.

Later in the `delete()` function you have another bug:

> ```
>         for(int i=pos; i > 0; i--){
> ```

The element at `pos` does not exist, so your loop needs to start at `pos-1`.

#### Inefficient delete

Right now, when you delete any element, you end up reheaping the entire heap.  What you should actually do is move the last element into the deleted slot, and then fix the heap from the deleted slot only (you need to check both against the parent and against the children).